# adb setting to load libraries from different directories

Tags: adb, hp-ux

I have a core file generated on an HP IA64 machine. I have the executable and shared objects related to the core file. I am trying to get the call stack using the adb debugger but the core file was generated on a machine I don't have access to, so the shared objects are in a different location than they are at the time the core file was generated.

I know if I have a similar situation using gdb I would do the following:

```
machine:user> gdb
(gdb) set solib-search-path path1:path2:path3
(gdb) file <name of executable file>
(gdb) core <name of core file>
```

Where the setting of solib-search-path tells gdb where to load shared libraries from.

Is there an equivalent if I'm using adb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be not to use adb in this situation but use gdb.